# Как сохранить изображения из БД MySQL на Google Drive с помощью Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь сохранить изображение в формате .jpg из БД MySQL на Google Drive пробовал создавать файл как из исходного BLOB, так и перекодировать его в base64, результат один - на диске изображения в неверной кодировке их невозможно открыть.

P.S. С данными в БД все нормально.

```js
function importImages() {

  var dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://199.99.99.99/db_name";
  var username = "user";
  var password = "password";
  var tableName = "table_name";
  var imageColumnName = "column_name";
  var sheetName = "Лист1";

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);

  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Images");

  while (rs.next()) {
    var imageBytes = rs.getBytes(imageColumnName);

    if (imageBytes) {
      var fileName = "image" + rs.getInt("id") + ".jpg";

      var imageBase64 = Utilities.base64Encode(imageBytes);

      var imageFile = folder.createFile(fileName, imageBase64, MimeType.JPEG);

      var imageFileUrl = imageFile.getUrl();

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      sheet.getRange(rs.getRow(), 4).setValue(imageFileUrl);
    }
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, так будет сложно ответить. Но `getBytes` слабо связаны с `base64Encode`. Т.е. вы изначально должны хранить в base64, или СУБД должна возвращать в нужном формате. Я бы, все же, смотрел в сторону коннектора, он же обвязывает все что через него проходит. Попробуйте взять ссылку на ячейку сущности и применить что-то из этого https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-blob Например, `getAppsScriptBlob()`. Т.к. в Скриптах Blob тоже не Blob ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, для BLOB из БД, кажется, нет прямого преобразования в объект Blob из Apps Script.
Нужно создать новый объект Blob из двоичных данных, тогда все работает верно:

```js
function importImages() {

  var dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://199.99.99.99/db_name";
  var username = "user";
  var password = "password";
  var tableName = "table_name";
  var imageColumnName = "column_name";
  var sheetName = "Лист1";

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);

  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Images");

  while (rs.next()) {
    var imageBlob = rs.getBlob(imageColumnName);
    
    if (imageBlob) {

      var fileName = "image" + rs.getInt("id") + ".jpg";

      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(imageBlob.getBytes(1, imageBlob.length()), "image/jpeg");
      blob.setName(fileName);

      var imageFile = folder.createFile(blob);
      var imageFileUrl = imageFile.getUrl();

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      sheet.getRange(rs.getRow(), 4).setValue(imageFileUrl);
    } 
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Спасибо @contributorpw

Comment: Отметьте как решение.